# I cannot generate a new keystore in java

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

I followed the steps [jsse reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) for java 7. 
I wrote this command to command prompt:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias duke -keyalg RSA \ -validity 7 -keystore keystore
```

However it throws error in command prompt:
"Use "keytool -help" for all available commands"

Do you have any ideas for solving this problem?

Comment: @jww It is about a tool distributed with the JDK and JRE and commonly used by programmers. There are hundreds of questions here about it. Also a `keystore` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jsse reference guide:

```
Solution 2: To interact with Navigator or IE, you should create certificates that use RSA-based keys. To do this, you need to specify the -keyalg RSA option when using keytool. For example:

keytool -genkeypair -alias duke \
    -keystore testkeys -keyalg rsa
```

The backslash `\` is to escape the newline, it looks like you are putting everything on the same line and keeping the `\`. Try removing it

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias duke -keyalg RSA -validity 7 -keystore keystore
```

Comment: I have apply this but i cant see .jks file. I think that this command create a .jks file but instead of it, it created .cer file.

Comment: the value you supply to `-keystore` will be the name of the keystore, so in the above command the keystore will be named `keystore`. You can rename it to `keystore.jks` or supply it in the command `keytool -genkeypair -alias duke -keyalg RSA -validity 7 -keystore mykeystore.jks`

Comment: In jsse tutorial, it says that: "Note: In this example, we authenticated the server only. If client authentication is desired, you will need to provide a similar keystore for the client's keys, and an appropriate truststore for the server." How can i do this? For server side, it defines 5 steps. But for client side, it is not defined properly.